# html to pdf in nodejs (no dependency to phantomjs)

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs, html-pdf

I am generating pdf from dynamic html (using handlebars)
using html-pdf package in nodejs.

The problem is that it is dependent to phantom js
that is now deprecated
And I am not allowed to use this package anymore.

What replacement can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf but this one has less options about footers/headers than html-pdf.

Otherwise I would use https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer